# Why I can not enter output value in the output console in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio

My python code in Visual Code Studio is having some problems:

```
def calculate(n):
    sum = (n*(n+1))/2
    return sum


in_value = int(input(">"))
answer = int(calculate())
print(answer)
```

But I can not enter the input value in the output console:
Why does that happen ?
Thanks for answering

Comment: You don't use `in_value` anywhere in your code. This code should raise an exception because you don't pass a required argument (`n`) to your function `calculate`.

Comment: @Selcuk, and also calculate function is called without argument

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the in_value into `calculate()` function.

```
answer = int(calculate(in_value))
```